# Adding nested plugin inside picture/image plugin in Django cms

Tags: plugins, nested, django-cms

I recently started exploring about nested plugins I want to add buttons or cards inside image plugin as per cms bootstrap https://github.com/django-cms/djangocms-picture if we set DJANGOCMS_PICTURE_NESTING = True if allows to add other plugins inside *image/picture plugin however it allows you to add all types of plugin but doesn't show on UI

Comment: It's unclear what's causing your problem, but I'd recommend also looking at an alternative frontend app; https://pypi.org/project/djangocms-frontend/